# For loop, arrays, step motor VHDL

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vhdl

I'm trying to implement a sequence in order to use a step motor using VHDL. Since I'm really new to VHDL I can't see what's missing in my code. I want to loop through an array to give the different steps to my variable named motor.

I'd appreciate any help.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity main is
    Port ( motor : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is

    type my_array is array (0 to 6) of std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); 
    signal sequence: my_array;
    sequence:= ("0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111");

begin
    variable i : std_logic:= '1';
    for i in sequence' range loop
      motor <= sequence(i);
   end loop;
end Behavioral;
```

These are the errors:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/main.vhd" Line 12: Syntax error near "sequence".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/main.vhd" Line 15: Syntax error near ":=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/main.vhd" Line 16: Syntax error near "loop".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users//main.vhd" Line 18: Syntax error near "loop".
ERROR:ProjectMgmt:496 - 4 error(s) found while parsing design hierarchy.
```

Comment: Well, first of all, you're missing a clock.

Answer (score 2):

Several things wrong here.

1) you can't perform signal assignment in the declaration area. You can initialise a signal there; the syntax is

```
signal sequence: my_array := ("0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111");
```

However since it's a lookup table and not something you want to change, make it a constant:

```
constant sequence: my_array := ("0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111");
```

2) Looping over an array is much simpler than that! The array declares its own datatype for the index, so `for i in sequence' range loop` implicitly declares its own `i` variable and I recommended you delete your own declaration of `i` (which is completely the wrong type anyway!)

3) As Godel says, there is no clock : and thus nothing to control the motor speed. You need to embed the loop in a clocked process, which is a standard design pattern; you'll find it in any guide to VHDL.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, this:

```
for i in sequence' range loop
      motor <= sequence(i);
   end loop;
```

is code which describes something which steps through the array.  However, you do not have anything to cause the model to wait a while.  You need to wrap that code in a process and either

- use `wait for 100 us;` (for example) if this is code which you do not expect to synthesise into a chip and just want to use a time delay
- create a clocked process and have an enable signal which goes to 1 each time you want a step:

Maybe something like this:

```
process 
  variable index : integer range sequence'range;
begin
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  if step_now = '1' then 
     if index >= sequence'high then
        index := sequence'low;
  else
     index := index + 1;
  end if;
  motor <= sequence(index);
end process;
```